# Make parent category an optgroup

Tags: categories

How to transform the parent category into an `optgroup`?

Demo of what I want: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pp7Ey/show/

Currently I have this code:

```
$cat = $_POST['cat'];

$data = array(
    ..
    'post_category' => array( $cat )
);

wp_insert_post( $data );

<?php wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&show_count=1&show_option_none=Select one&class=cat&hierarchical=1&name=cat'); ?>
```

Comment: Please stop asking the same question again and again. Improve the first question instead.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to `extend` the `Walker_CategoryDropdown` walker. A very, very simple version of that is this:

```
class Top_level_Optgroup extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {

  var $optgroup = false;

  function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);

    $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);
    if (0 == $depth) {
//    $this->optgroup = true;
      $output .= "<optgroup class=\"level-$depth\" label=\"".$cat_name."\" >";
    } else {
      $output .= "<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->term_id."\"";
      if ( $category->term_id == $args['selected'] )
              $output .= ' selected="selected"';
      $output .= '>';
      $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
      if ( $args['show_count'] )
              $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
      $output .= "</option>";
    }

  }

  function end_el(&$output,$object,$depth) {
    if (0 == $depth/* && true == $this->optgroup*/) {
      $output .= '</optgroup>';
    }
  }
}

// usage test
wp_dropdown_categories(
  array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'show_count' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => 'Select one',
    'class' => 'cat',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'name' => 'cat',
    'walker' => new Top_level_Optgroup
  )
);
```

That assumes that the the topmost-- `depth === 0`-- category is an `optgroup`. That is very simple logic, but seems to match your example. This walker does not look for nor does it care about the presence or absence of category children and probably won't work correctly if your actual category structure is more complicated than that in your example.

Comment: some srict php warnings on `end_el` definition, but once resolved code works

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_categories()` where you will have more control over the data and build up your own dropdown.

So for example, when you get the categories (add your own arguments to it):

```
$categories = get_categories(); 

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (0 == $category->parent) {
      // This will be an optgroup
    } else {
      // This will be an option
    }
  }
```

Hope that helps.